# C# variable and positioning

Tags: c#

so I'm new to programming and coding. I have a code that I'm writing in c# and after the weight I'm supposed to add the word pounds to the end of it. Whats the easiest way to do so?

```
using System;

namespace CSE1301_BMRP
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write ("Hello! Whats your name: ");
            string name; 
            name = Console.ReadLine ();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
            Console.Write ("How old are you?: ");
            string age; 
            age = Console.ReadLine ();
            Console.WriteLine (" I am, " + age);
            Console.WriteLine ("Wow, you're young. How much do you weigh?: ");
            float weight;
            weight = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.WriteLine ("Your weight is " + weight ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the {}-Button to indent the code; you can check the result in the preview before posting.

Comment: You know how to concatenate `string` and `float` but you don't know how to do `string` + `float` + `string`?'

Comment: `Whats the easiest way to do so?` Apparently to try nothing at all and post an SO question for some rep hunter to answer.   *et viola*

Comment: In my post I stated that I'm new to programming if I knew how I wouldn't have asked but thanks for your unhelpful comment Camilo.

Answer (score -1):

How about `"Your weight is "+weight+" pounds."` or `string.Format("Your weight is {0} pounds.", weight)`?

Comment: I'd actually be best with `Console.WriteLine("Your weight is {0} pounds", weight)` since `Console.WriteLine` already supports formatting. However, you shouldn't do other people's homework

Comment: There is even *more bestest* approach - `using static System.Console; ....WriteLine($"Your weight is {weight} pounds")`...

Comment: +1 "more bestest approach".. wouldve been nice to have someone outline all 3 ways, and explain the differences/pros/cons.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep your variable `weight` as a `float` try this

```
float weight;
weight = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Your weight is " + weight + "pounds");
```

Comment: This adds nothing to what @phi1010 already answered. Please read [answer]

Comment: What do you mean by 'keep your variable as a float` how does the OP or the other answer change it?